# Images blurry on product page in firefox and IE magento

Tags: magento

I have a website made in Magento, and some of the product images on the product pages are blurry in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but not Chrome or Safari. EDIT: Actually, I just noticed that it does it briefly on Chrome before fixing itself.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

The URL is: http://centaurrecords.com/store/johannes-brahms-piano-pieces.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your zoom module uses full images that are being scaled down by the browser, what does not give the best results. Most modern browsers automatically optimize scaled down images, but some gives a better rendering than others (this is why the image is nicer with Chrome).